# Как сделать на PHP, чтобы при попытке закрытия сайта появлялось окно с каким-то текстом?

Tags: php

Сразу говорю, что всякие beforeunload и onbeforeunload от Javascript не подходят.

Comment: А PHP ничего не знает о закрытии сайта, поэтому ему так или иначе придется делать это через JS.

Comment: beforeunload это единственный возможный способ, других нет

Comment: Пожалуйста, не  делайте так. На такие сайты возвращаться не хочется

Comment: @axmed2004 вот точно. Я на такие сайты второй раз не захожу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, закрытие браузера, это просто закрытие приложения, такое действие. Никакие запросы на сервер слать он не будет. Соответственно, ваш демон на `PHP` об этом не узнает. Можно кончено с помощью `JS`, например, по `WebSocket`, отловить событие закрытия **вкладки** на браузере, и отправить на сервер.

Но вообще конечно, такого делать не желательно. Вы же не собираетесь делать баннеры из 2000-х?

Answer (score 1):

php - работает на сервере, а окно браузера, как известно, клиентская часть. Посмотрите, как эмитировать поведение кнопки закрыть на JS